# OpenSearch - querying unique data with timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I am trying to get data from OpenSearch that will include distinct values and timestamps. Then I need to find the timestamp when the specific value has occurred.

Example: OpenSearch is storing clicks on my webpage and I want to find when the specific click has occurred (16th click).

This is my query:

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": startDate,
              "lte": endDate
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "event": "click"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "unique_users": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "user_id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "user_id"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "ipaddress": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "ipaddress"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried with this "aggs" but it returns count:

```
"aggs": {
  multi_field_cardinality: {
    cardinality: {
      script:
        "doc['ipaddress'].value + '#' + user_id'].value",
    },
  }
```

Thanks in advance!